# ZLib: DeflatePrime number of bits of Z_PARTIAL_FLUSH

Tags: c++, c, compression, zlib

In the ZLIB Manual it is stated that `Z_PARTIAL_FLUSH` always flush an extra **10 bits.**  So that we correct for that using `deflatePrime` when we want to append later.

But why then is `gzlog.c` containing logic to find dynamically the bit count `if *buf` . According to the specs this is not needed and only the `else` is needed to set it to 10?

```c
        if (*buf) {
            log->back = 1;
            while ((*buf & ((uint)1 << (8 - log->back++))) == 0)
                ;       /* guaranteed to terminate, since *buf != 0 */
        }
        else
            log->back = 10;
```

Comment: I think this needs a bit more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because most of the time not all of the ten bits are written. Only in the case where the last byte is a zero are all ten bits written, because by chance (a one-in-eight chance) there were six bits pending to be written before the ten-bit empty static block.